# Chatbox with the capability of natural language processing

Tags: search

We need a feature of chatbot in the site with natural language processing (NLP) capability.
The chatbot will be having multiple persona.  The users can to come to the site and they can select a persona to talk with.

Say for example: If I come to the site and select a persona and ask in the chat, what are treatment methods available for dengue?
The chatbot should able to give the answer accordingly from content repository in the site.

Any solution for this available in drupal + any third party tools?

Comment: There are quite a few modules poping out under : https://www.drupal.org/search/site/bot?f[0]=ss_meta_type%3Amodule I don't which of them are of relevance